The gold badge was not awarded to me for what reason?
Currently, this question has over $10,000$ views. It is a  famous  question. I think Gold  badge should appear on my profile page.

Congratulations Jasmine. Your question now does have actually 10000 views. I still don't see an additional gold badge. Maybe someone will point out that the real algorithm behind this (maybe it needs one more view or perhaps there is a a time lag). Either way, your question was of interest to lots of people, which is what matters.

Thanks you  @Srini

If you hover over "10k views" you can see that the question has 9957 views. I suppose that the badge will be awarded after the question reaches 10000 views.

You can see the questions with certain number of views using views operator in search.
Here is a SEDE query which can be used to display your most viewed questions. (Keep in mind that SEDE is updated only once a week.)

why does it show $10$ k views instead of $9957?$

@jasmine You can check some of the older posts around this topic, such as: Does "k" really mean 1000?

Is shows $10$K when rounded to $2$ significant figures.

Jasmine, in case you are wondering why you still haven't got the badge (which was the case when I checked a bit earlier) despite having 10000 views now, see the explanation here.

Actually you got it now. I will keep this answer just in case another user wonders the same in a different situation.
